# How to remove table border

Tags: tables

This could be a silly question, but how would you modify my code so that 
the portion of the line indicated is removed?

[image: Current output]

```
  \documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{caption}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{lll|c|llll}
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\text{Group B}}  &  & \multicolumn{4}{r}{\text{Group A}}\\[0.124cm]
%\hline
    &  & 1 & 0 &   &   &   &  \\[0.024cm]
   & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 8 &  \\[0.024cm]
 7 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 9 & 4\\[0.024cm]
   & 5 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 7\\[0.024cm]
   & 2 & 5 & 4 & 4 & 6\\[0.024cm]
   &   & 2 & 5 & 1 &  &\\[0.024cm]
   &   &   & 6 & 2 & 4\\[0.024cm]
   &   &   & 7 & 1  & \\[0.024cm]
%3 & 14 & 7 & 6\\
\end{tabular}
\centering
\caption*{$8|5$ means $8.5$ seconds}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `\multicolumn` that does not have any vertical bar in the empty cell. (I also kicked out a lot of packages that are not needed here.)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{lll|c|llll}
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\text{Group B}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{r}{\text{Group A}}\\[0.124cm]
%\hline
    &  & 1 & 0 &   &   &   &  \\[0.024cm]
   & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 8 &  \\[0.024cm]
 7 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 9 & 4\\[0.024cm]
   & 5 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 7\\[0.024cm]
   & 2 & 5 & 4 & 4 & 6\\[0.024cm]
   &   & 2 & 5 & 1 &  &\\[0.024cm]
   &   &   & 6 & 2 & 4\\[0.024cm]
   &   &   & 7 & 1  & \\[0.024cm]
%3 & 14 & 7 & 6\\
\end{tabular}
\centering
\caption*{$8|5$ means $8.5$ seconds}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `{tabular}` by `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you only have to put the key `first-row` (by design, the rules in `{NiceTabular}` are not drawn in the so-called ``first-row'').

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{NiceTabular}{lll|c|llll}[first-row]
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\text{Group B}}  & & \multicolumn{4}{r}{\text{Group A}}\\[0.124cm]
%\hline
    &  & 1 & 0 &   &   &   &  \\[0.024cm]
   & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 8 &  \\[0.024cm]
 7 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 9 & 4\\[0.024cm]
   & 5 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 7\\[0.024cm]
   & 2 & 5 & 4 & 4 & 6\\[0.024cm]
   &   & 2 & 5 & 1 &  &\\[0.024cm]
   &   &   & 6 & 2 & 4\\[0.024cm]
   &   &   & 7 & 1  & \\[0.024cm]
%3 & 14 & 7 & 6\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\centering
\caption*{$8|5$ means $8.5$ seconds}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]